Agora IOT SDK fails to Initialize
I followed agora IOT SDK for android. but the SDK fails to initialize with error -20. what does this error code mean? and i wanna know whether this IOT SDK still supports for older android verison like 7.0. Please help me resolve this issue.

I can check this documentation https://docs.agora.io/en/iot/overview/supported-platforms?platform=android.
This documentation describes that the IOT SDK has support for Android 4.1 and higher.
